# Encoding A Decimal Value Into a Fixed Number of Bits

Tags: c, encoding, bit-manipulation

There is a heated, ongoing disagreement between myself and someone more senior that I need to resolve.  Thus, I turn to you internets.  Don't fail me now!

The objective is to take a decimal value and encode it into 24 bits.  It's a simple linear scale so that 0x000000 is the min value and 0xFFFFFF is the max value.

We both agree on the basic formula of how to achieve this: (max-min)/range.  The issue is the denominator.  The other party says that this should be 1 << 24 (one left shifted 24 bits).  This yields 16777216.  I argue (and have seen this done previously) that the denominator should be 0xFFFFFF, or 16777215.

Who is correct?

Comment: The real question is: "What is 0xFFFFFF in decimal?".

Comment: Sorry, it's a unsigned value that gets packed or 16777215.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?  You didn't specify a representation method, you're asking what 2^24 is vs 2^24-1.

Comment: The orignal value is a double.  It needs to be packed into 24 bits where 0xFFFFFF is the maximum value the specific double can be and 0x000000 is the min value.  So let's say that I'm encoding speed for a car.  0.0 mph would be 0x000000 and 150.0mph would be represented by 0xFFFFFF.  It's a simple linear scale from there.

Comment: What are you talking about?  It has nothing to do with any of my comments.

Comment: What are you talking about?  0xFFFFFF is represented as a unsigned integer, so it is 16777215 in decimal.

Comment: Yes.  That's your question.

Comment: No, my question is whether or not I should use 0xFFFFFF or 1 << 24 or 1677216 for the denominator of the scaling factor when packing the double into the 24 bits.

Comment: David, this isn't that complex.  Please see Tejolote's post to help you understand.

Comment: @awpitt13 I know I was pointing out that it is **not** that complex by trying to rephrase the OP's long-winded question prose into a single sentence..

Comment: How am I being a dick?  I'm pointing out that this is not the best format for your question.  You should just ask, what is 0xFFFFFF in decimal to get your answer, no need for the long prose.  That's all.  Sorry if it came across dick-ish, that's not my intent.

Comment: That aside, do know that floats are already packed into 24bits for the integer part and the remainder into the decimal part?  So you can probably pack this range into a `float`.

Comment: @DavidCowden: If by “floats” you mean IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point format, they are not packed into 24 bits for the integer part and the remainder into decimal. The significand is 24 bits, and it may represent entirely integer values, entirely fractional values, or a mix, depending on the exponent. Most of the significand is explicitly encoded in 23 bits. The remaining bits are one for the sign and eight for the exponent (which implicitly encodes another bit of the significand).

Comment: None of the answers so far account for skewing of the distribution caused by mapping very few input values to the final bin or rounding during calculation changing the results from the ideal mathematical calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd second @Tejolote's answer, since shifting a `1` 0 or more times will give you a range between 1..1677216.

```
(32-bit number)
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 // (1 << 0)
0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 // (1 << 24)
```

If you were to get a bitmask of those 24 bits, you would get a range from 1 to 0 (probably not what you intended):

```
  (mask to a 24-bit number)
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 // (1 << 0)
& 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 // mask
  ==================================
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 // result of '1', correct
```

and

```
  0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 // (1 << 24)
& 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 // mask
  ==================================
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 // result of '0', wrong
```

What you want instead is a range from 0 to 16777215:

```
& 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 // (1 << 0) - 1
  0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 // mask
  ==================================
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 // result of '0', correct
```

and

```
  0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 // (1 << 24) - 1
& 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 // mask
  ==================================
  0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 // result of '16777215', correct
```

Answer (score 4):

The denominator should definitely be 16777215 as you described. 2^24 is 16777216 but that number cannot be represented with a 24 bit number. The max number is 2^24 - 1 (16777215) or 0xFFFFFF like you say.

Answer (score 1):

OP "So let's say that I'm encoding speed for a car. 0.0 mph would be 0x000000 and 150.0mph would be represented by 0xFFFFFF. It's a simple linear scale from there."

Yes 16777215 = 0xFFFFFF - 0x000000

```
0.0 --> 0x000000
150.0 --> 0xFFFFFF

y = dy/dx(x - x0) + y0 = (0xFFFFFF - 0x000000)/(150.0 - 0.0)*(x - 0.0) + 0x000000
```

But if senior was thinking the decimal value on the upper end represented the speed one could approach, but not attain.

```
0.0 --> 0x000000
150.0 --> 0xFFFFFF + 1
```

16777216 = 0xFFFFFF + 1 - 0x000000

I'd recommend buying your senior a brew.  Learn from them - they cheat